# Comparing two sets in SPARQL to find instances in Set 1 that do not exist in Set 2

Tags: sparql

I am trying to create two sets in SPARQL, and return the number of instances in ?set1 that do not exist in ?set2. I am trying to do this all in SPARQL, and I was not able to find a good resource on how to do this through FILTER, as well as using MINUS, but not having any luck.

SELECT COUNT(?set1)
WHERE {
?S ?P ?set1 .
?Q ?R ?set2 .
FILTER (*member in ?set1 doesn't exist in ?set2*
}

Comment: Just to be clear, could you provide meaningful example variables? Is it something like `?organization1 ?hasMember ?member` and `?organization2 ?hasOwner ?owner` ?

Comment: This can be thought of employees being issued company electronics. They are not allowed to use computers that are not issued to them by the company. The first line gets all of the serial numbers they have. The second gets a list of all serial numbers owned by the company.

What I need is the query to return nothing when everything is good, and something when the rules are being broken.


Select ?ElectronicNumber 

WHERE {
?employee :usesElectroic ?ElectronicNumber ;

?company :ownsElectronic ?ElectronicInventory ;

FILTER (?Computer NOT IN ?ElectronicInventory)

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FILTER NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?electronic) AS ?count)
WHERE {
  ?employee :usesElectronic ?electronic .
  
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?company :ownsElectronic ?electronic . }
}
```

This counts the devices that

- are used by any employee, and
- are not owned by any company.

If you just need to know *if* such a case exists, and you are not interested in the count, you could use an ASK query instead, which returns TRUE or FALSE. For that, replace the whole `SELECT` line with `ASK`.

Comment: This was great and very helpful. It did get me to a solution, but that has me thinking about adding to this.

If I have a SELECT that counts two values, am I able to use an ASK to return TRUE/FALSE based on if the numbers match, or return a property if a certain value is larger?

Comment: @JosephShea: The first case is possible. Your ASK query needs to contain 1) the SELECT query as subquery, and 2) a `FILTER` that checks if the numbers from the subquery match.